# How do I activate the Lanayru Desert Mining Co. Stone Cache power generator?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I've activated two of the three generators to power the machine that opens the entrance to the Lanayru Mining Co.

However, I can't figure out how to get to the generator at the end of the Stone Cache.

There's a large area of sand too far for me to run across, and after I timeshift, there's just a big hole there.

How do I get across this area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Arid Present:

- Kill an Amplius (the giant rollers) and then chase and get on it's shell.
- The current will allow you to ride it to the end.
- (optional) Now climb up the crates to your left and walk along the top, you'll find a crate you can push down to create a shortcut for future use.

Now hit the time crystal in the middle of the room to be in the Green Past:

- Use the beetle to grab an Amplius Egg and carry it over to the gate control machine.
- Roll the Amplius egg into the machine.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I needed to defeat the enemy closer to the area I couldn't cross... it's one of those sand pits with a current, so the shell is pulled across.  From there, I used the Beetle to trigger the timeshift and then bring one of the electrified enemies to the power device for the door.